# How to link to the right page of a topic in a search result?

Tags: php, sql, search, pagination

I have a search function in a forum where the search results will be displayed 10 at the time. The user can then look at the next or previous 10 search results. The results show different topics where the searched words are to be found. Everything works like I want it to.

The issue is when I want the user to be able to click a result and end up on the right page of that topic. For instance post nr 14 in a certain topic must be viewed on page 2 ( using `LIMIT 10,10` in the SQL query on the topic page). I send the `LIMIT` parameter as a $_GET in the link.

How can I retrieve the row number of each topic in the results out of the total numbers of that specific topic when ordering by the date it was posted? Everything is always displayed in that order. I would like to use `$nr = $nr-1; //and then`

```
 $limit = floor($nr / 10) * 10;
```

on that number to be able to send the right `LIMIT` parameter with the link in the search result.

Here's the PDO used to get the search results:

```
$query = 'SELECT t.topic_id, t.topic_cat, t.topic_subject, p.post_content, p.post_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) AS post_date
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN topics t ON p.post_topic = t.topic_id 
WHERE p.post_content LIKE :search OR t.topic_subject LIKE :search ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) DESC LIMIT :start, :size';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':search', '%'.$search.'%');
$statement->bindValue(':start', $start2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':size', $pagesize, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();

    while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $array[$row['topic_subject']][] = $row['post_id'];
        $nr = count($array[$row['topic_subject']]) - 1;
        echo '<div class="search_result"><div class="search_topic"><a href="topic_view.php?id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '&amp;cat_id=' . $row['topic_cat'] . '
        &amp;start=' . floor($nr / 10) * 10 . '#anchor_' . $row['post_id'] . '">' . $row['topic_subject'] . '</a><span style="float:right;color:#696969">' 
        . date("M d, Y",$row['post_date']) . '</span></div><div class="search_post">' . $row['post_content'] . '</div></div>';
    }
} $statement->closeCursor();
```

It is the `start` parameter in the link that I somehow need to grab in the query so I don't have to do a new DB call for each `post_id` in the `while loop`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have the row number, and you want to find out on which page it will be?

Comment: I have the id of each post that is displayed in the search result (the headline of each result being the topic), but to be able to send the user to the right page of that topic I need to know what number to use in the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming, that you only know, the ID of the post, I would go like this:

```
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    `posts`
WHERE
    date <= ( SELECT date FROM `posts` WHERE post_id = '$id' )
ORDER BY
    date DESC;
```

This will give you the number of row this post is. After that, just do some php code like:

```
$start = floor( $nr / 10 ) * 10;
$end = ceil( $nr / 10 ) * 10;
```

For multiple IDs:

```
SELECT topic_id, (
    SELECT
        count(*)
    FROM
        `posts`
    WHERE
        date <= ( SELECT date FROM `posts` u1 WHERE u1.topic_id = u2.topic_id )
    ) AS row
FROM
    `posts` u2
WHERE
    topic_id IN ( '$id1', '$id2', '$id3' )
ORDER BY
    date DESC;
```

Comment: I assume it must be WHERE topic_id = '$topic_id'? As I need the number of that post in the topic. 

But wouldn't I have to do that query for every single search result?

Comment: I though you needed for only one, will rewrite in a min.

Comment: Ok. The search results are being displayed with PDO: while ($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { } so would be nice to somehow be able to include the right start parameter in each result set by just incorporating some extra select in the original query.

Comment: @NewInTheBusiness Edited answer. Sorry m8, that's the best I could come up with, I'm sure there is a better way though.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = 'SELECT :start as start, t.topic_id, t.topic_cat, t.topic_subject,
p.post_content, p.post_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) AS post_date
FROM posts p 
LEFT JOIN topics t ON p.post_topic = t.topic_id 
WHERE p.post_content LIKE :search OR t.topic_subject LIKE :search
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.post_date) DESC LIMIT :start, :size';
```

then access through `$start = $row['start']`

```
$nr = count($array[$row['topic_subject']])+$start - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem as you said. I think this links is useful for you.

I have done these successfully, I hope be useful you:
 1. http://www.awcore.com/dev/1/3/Create-Awesome-PHPMYSQL-Pagination_en
 2. http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html